# NPM registry install fails on non-registry dependencies

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, npm, nexus

I'm trying to install my Ionic App through the registry with it's dependencies.
I try to achieve this with `npm i --loglevel verbose` while my `~/.npmrc` looks like this:

```
//nexus.OMMITED.com/repository/:_auth=OMMITED
registry=http://nexus.OMMITED.com/repository/npm-all
always-auth=true
```

When watching the command run it *seems* to go just fine, until we hit other non-registry dependencies, suddenly I'm met with an authorisation error.

Here is a paste of the command: https://hasteb.in/hejigopo.sql

As you see it fails on `@angular/http@6.1.2` in this instance, but this variables between random `@angular` dependencies or `@ionic-native`

**What I have tried so far...**

1. Changing `always-auth` to `true` or `false`
2. Running as Super User
3. Trying different tokens
4. using `_authToken` instead of `_auth`
5. Google, a lot, but it turns out my problem is very unique.
6. `npm login --registry=http://nexus.OMMITED.com/repository/npm-all` with both `--auth=TOKEN_OMITTED` and `--authToken=TOKEN_OMITTED` where npm tells me `npm WARN invalid config auth-type="TOKEN_OMITTED"` and prompts for a username, my username however is an email address which throws this error: `npm WARN Name may not contain non-url-safe chars` only to infinitely keep prompting for another username.

Comment: I'm noticing the first line of your npmrc file appears to be a comment using `//`. Per the [npmrc docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc#comments) comments don't use `//` for comments, but instead `#` or `;`. Not sure how this would necessarily affect it, but something to try changing.

Comment: Additionally, is that first line attempting to set `_auth` for a scope of the url? you should try setting just `_auth` to your token to see if that works. If you need to scope things, the docs I linked in my previous comment seem to indicate that to scope something you  do `@scope:_auth=...` so that's something to try. (Here's some docs on [npm scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) to checkout if you're curious)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how, or why, but *somehow* it works now if I specify the full registry in the command likeso:

`npm --registry=http://nexus.OMITTED.com/repository/npm-all/ install`

While my `~/.npmrc` looks like this:

```
//nexus.OMITTED.com/repository/:_authToken=OMITTED
registry=http://nexus.OMITTED.com/repository/npm-all/
_auth=OMITTED
email=bob@OMITTED.nl
```

None of this makes sense to me whatsoever, but I'm glad it works for a change.

*If anyone ends up writing a proper answer to this as to why this works, how this works and why the normal way doesn't, then I will gladly accept it as the answer and reward the bounty.*

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use npm login with Nexus Repo 3:

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Node+Packaged+Modules+and+npm+Registries#NodePackagedModulesandnpmRegistries-AuthenticationUsingRealmandLogin

And make sure the npm bearer token realm is enabled under "security/realms" in the Nexus UI.

That said, the error is 403, not 401.  This means you're getting rejected due to permissions.  I suggest checking the nexus request.log and making sure the 403's are coming from Nexus.  They could be coming from your http proxy server.  If they are coming from Nexus it means the user has been authenticated, but doesn't have permissions in nexus to download from that repo.

Comment: using `npm login` requires me to enter a username, my username is an email address which appearantly has url-unsafe-characters, because of this it won't allow me any further. I've also tried adding my Token as an argument through appending a `--auth` or `--authToken` argument followed by my token, but this proved to be uneventful.

Comment: The error accompanied by the command using `--auth` is: `npm WARN invalid config auth-type="MY_TOKEN", `
` Token omitted for obvious reasons. When I use `--authToken` it just prompts me for a username again.

Comment: Please mind that the `403` errorcode *also* seems to be "random", sometimes it's `403`, sometimes it's `401`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command after changing .npmrc file
npm run npm-auth

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).